# If condition is true get MIN(), else get next SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table called 'events', and wanted to grab the first entry by the 'created_at' date. However, if the first event (MIN(events.created_at)) has a title that contains 'test', I would instead like to return the next event for that user (by the created_at). And if the user only has one event, just return that one event.

Is there an easy way to do this with a query?

This is about as far as I can get; it returns the first event by created_at

```
SELECT MIN(events.created_at) 'event_created_at', events.user_id, events.title, MIN(events.type) 'type'
FROM events
GROUP BY events.user_id
```

This is for an SQL DBMS

Comment: Please edit question and show example table data and expected output, and tag with database platform being used.  Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @scsimon That won't handle it if the user has only one event.

Comment: good point @Shawn

Comment: SQL isn't a DBMS, it's a basic language. Do you mean Microsoft SQL Server? If so, what version?

Comment: Also, if you have one event that was entered by multiple users, do you want the earliest entry of each of the users, or the earliest entry of all users with the "test" condition > ie User 1 enters "Test", then User2 enters "Event1", you want only User2's entry, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you really want the full information about the event.  If so, `GROUP BY` is the wrong approach.

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.user_id
                                order by (case when e.title not like '%test%' then 1 else 2 end) desc,
                                         e.created_at asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

When you want to select rows from a group, then window functions are usually a better approach than `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, `WITH TIES` would be a good option

```
select top 1 with ties
   events.user_id
   ,events.title
   ,events.created_at
   ,events.type
from events
order by row_number() over (partition by events.user_id order by case when events.title = 'test' then 2 else 1 end, events.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Gordon beat me to it. Teach me not to refresh before posting an answer. I agree though, go with the Window Function. The only difference between mine an his is checking for a `NULL` `created_at` date.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04b71/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE events ( user_id int, title varchar(20), type varchar(20), created_at datetime ) ;

INSERT INTO events ( user_id, title, type, created_at )
VALUES 
    ( 1, 'Event1', 'Event', '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
  , ( 2, 'Event1', 'Event', '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 2, 'Event1', 'Event', '2018-06-01 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 1, 'Event2', 'Event', '2018-11-22 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 5, 'Event2', 'test', '2018-11-22 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 5, 'Event2', 'Event', '2018-01-02 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
  , ( 5, 'Event3', 'TesT', '2018-01-03 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 5, 'Event3', 'NoTest', '2018-01-03 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
  , ( 4, 'Event3', 'test', '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' )
  , ( 1, 'Event4', 'TeSt', '2018-01-04 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
  , ( 2, 'Event5', 'Event', null )
  , ( 3, 'Event5', 'Event', '2018-01-05 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
  , ( 4, 'Event6', 'test', '2018-01-07 00:00:00.000' ) 
  , ( 4, 'Event6', 'test', '2018-01-06 00:00:00.000' ) /* This one */
 ;
```

**Main Query**:

```
SELECT s1.created_at AS event_created_at
  , s1.user_id
  , s1.title
  , s1.type
FROM (
  SELECT e.title, e.user_id, e.type, e.created_at
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY e.title
        ORDER BY e.title, CASE WHEN e.type='test' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END DESC, e.created_at
      ) AS rn
  FROM events e
  WHERE e.created_at IS NOT NULL
) s1
WHERE s1.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04b71/1/0)**:

```
|     event_created_at | user_id |  title |   type |
|----------------------|---------|--------|--------|
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |       1 | Event1 |  Event |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z |       5 | Event2 |  Event |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00Z |       5 | Event3 | NoTest |
| 2018-01-04T00:00:00Z |       1 | Event4 |   TeSt |
| 2018-01-05T00:00:00Z |       3 | Event5 |  Event |
| 2018-01-06T00:00:00Z |       4 | Event6 |   test |
```